# Layover in airport with self transfer, what are my options?

Tags: layovers, airport-transfer, venice

I'm traveling to Madrid through Venice (Marco Polo airport), with self transfer option, which means I have to leave the airport security then check in again. I have some questions. I was planning to stay in the transit area where I can at least sleep between 7 PM and 3 AM. Then clear security and come back again for my 6 AM trip. Is there a problem with that? I have my bag with me but Wizzair might take it at boarding, which means i have to go to baggage claim. Is it a big deal if I leave it out there until 3 AM?
Note: according to Venice airport website, sleeping outside security region is not allowed.

Comment: This may help - https://www.sleepinginairports.net

Comment: If your carry-on is put in the hold at the gate it will be delivered at the aircraft on arrival, not go to baggage claim.

Comment: Are you talking about Venice Marco Polo airport, or Treviso? I doubt an unclaimed bag rolling round on a carousel for 7+ hours would go unnoticed by airport staff.

Comment: Marco polo, i thought so too
I didn't knows the bag is returned at the gate, that makes things much easier thank you

Comment: @60levelchange in my experience this varies a lot. You will generally get it back at the aircraft if it’s a small aircraft (regional jet) **and** you don’t get a jetway. In other cases it’s highly variable. Air France Cityjet flights from Paris to Dublin would be delivered at baggage claim for instance, while the other way around it would be delivered at the aircraft. No idea what the practice is at Marco Polo for Wizzair.